# how to override getView() method in activity extend Listactivity

Tags: android, listview, listactivity, getview

My project have a listview and MainActivity extend ListActivity, so I work "Alt+Shift+S" to add method getView() but I can not find getView() in this list.

Please show me, I need call getView() method. 
Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Custom Adapter class??

Comment: the listactivity wont override this method, as its not hers to begin with. you have to attach an adapter to the listview in order to handle how the views are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getView() is a method of List adapter. So to Override it you need to set a custom adapter to your activity
ref: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return rowView;
  }
}
```

in your Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
        MySimpleArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

Comment: so if i have not class extend ListAdapter i will not call getView()?

Comment: you can not Override it, but I think you can call it like this:
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, numberOfItems);
adapter.getView(position, convertView, parent);